# LNK2019 when define UNICODE/_UNICODE

Tags: windows, winapi

I am using TCHAR and I get the error when I define UNICODE / _UNICODE. Here is my code.

*function.h*

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

BOOL bLogging(LPCTSTR szContent, ...);
```

*function.cpp*

```
#include "function.h"

BOOL bLogging(LPCTSTR szContent, ...)
{
    body of function
}
```

*plugin.cpp*

```
#include "function.h"

bool pluginInit(PLUG_INITSTRUCT* initStruct)
{
    bLogging(TEXT("hello, world!"));
}
```

The above code makes the error

```
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl bLogging(char const *,...)" (?bLogging@@YAHPBDZZ) referenced in function "bool __cdecl pluginInit(struct PLUG_INITSTRUCT *)" (?pluginInit@@YA_NPAUPLUG_INITSTRUCT@@@Z)
```

But without the UNICODE / _UNICODE, it builds as ASCII characters, it works well.

```
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Make sure you do a full clean and rebuild, and also watch for `#include`'s other than `function.h`. It is generally safer to `#define` globals like `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` in the compiler settings, as opposed to individual header files.

Comment: Added Windows and WinApi tags.  Remove C++ tag.

Comment: You can see from the error mesasge that `LPCTSTR` is still an ANSI `char const*`, so your `#define UNICODE` is not taking effect. My guess is that somebody already did an `#include <windows.h>` before including your header, so you are defining `UNICODE` too late.

Comment: It looks to me like `LPCTSTR` is doing the right thing but `TEXT` is not.

Comment: As posted, the code doesn't produce the error. The error is in a place we cannot see. Using precompiled headers, for example, is one way to introduce preprocessor symbols that don't match.

Comment: @RaymondChen you correct! I included a windows.h before define UNICODE / _UNICODE

Comment: @DenRua You can [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to share the solution or [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.) helps you to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Raymond's comment is probably the correct answer. Otherwise, your code looks fine.

Unless you are trying to have backwards compatibility support for Windows 95, you don't need TCHAR macros.  Simpler to just avoid this stuff and use either `const wchar_t*` or `LPCWSTR` as your string type.

Adjusting your code as an example:

*function.h*

```
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>

BOOL bLogging(const wchar_t* szContent, ...);
```

*function.cpp*

```
#include "function.h"

BOOL bLogging(const wchar_t* szContent, ...)
{
    body of function
}
```

*plugin.cpp*

```
#include "function.h"

bool pluginInit(PLUG_INITSTRUCT* initStruct)
{
    bLogging(L"Hello World");
}
```

Comment: i have solved my problem. I included windows.h before define UNICODE / _UNICODE. Thank for your help but I like to keep code work with both wchar and char.

Comment: There's actually no sound reason to keep using TCHAR macros in the year 2020.  Pick a character encoding and stick with it.